# how do you focus on an iframe which window contains "window.onclick"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

There's an html canvas game which I would like to put on my website. The thing is the window contains `window.onclick` which doesn't sound like much of an issue but its mildly annoying having to *click on the `iframe` every time I load the page*.  so I want to make a way for the page to auto focus on the frame without me having to click on.

the problem comes it where `document.querySelector('iframe').focus()` doesn't work. it does put the viewers focus on the iframe, but *the framed window doesn't have any sound*. i think it's because it's focusing on the iframe but it's not focusing on the window in the iframe, if that makes any sense. the window, on the other hand, does have a script to focus on the window `window.onclick = function () { window.focus(); }`. but I kind of want it to be like `document.querySelector('iframe').onfocus = function () { window.focus(); }`  which wouldn't work for *obvious* reasons.

i've tried a few things, none of which worked.

```
<iframe src="https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/4423984/index.html" width="800" height="600" scrolling="no" onload="this.focus()"></iframe>
```

­

```
<iframe src="https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/4423984/index.html" width="400" height="300" scrolling="no" onload="this.click()"></iframe>
```

­

```
<iframe src="https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/4423984/index.html" width="400" height="300" scrolling="no" onfocus="this.click()" onload="this.focus()"></iframe>
```

­

```
<iframe src="https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/4423984/index.html" width="800" height="600" scrolling="no" style="border: 2px solid purple;" onload="this.contentWindow.focus()"></iframe>
```

so i don't think the window understands the `click()` function.

what i want is for this script to return true

```
    function testAudio(){playTestAudio();return _yb1&&g_WebAudioContext&&g_WebAudioContext.state!==_fa1._ga1}function playTestAudio(){if(_yb1||_zb1)return;_zb1=true;var _lb1=new Audio(_X91);_lb1.controls=false;_lb1.autoplay=true;_lb1.preload="none";document.body.appendChild(_lb1);try{var _Bb1=_lb1.play();if(_Bb1!==undefined){_Bb1.then(function(){debug("WebAudio autoplay test passed.");_yb1=true;_zb1=false;_Cb1();document.body.removeChild(_lb1)}).catch(function(error){console.log("WebAudio autoplay test failed: ",error);document.body.removeChild(_lb1);
_zb1=false;_Db1()})}else {console.log("WebAudio autoplay test failed: Playback promise invalid.");document.body.removeChild(_lb1);_zb1=false;_Db1()}}catch(_wC){debug("WebAudio autoplay test failed with exception: "+_wC);document.body.removeChild(_lb1);_zb1=false;_Db1()}}
```

if there is a method of focusing on the framed window, please tell me. if theres any **javascript** or **jquery**, it can be in a seperate `<script>` tag, though i want it to be a shorter script. not too long, thats all.

Answer (score 0):

To access iframe contents, you will need to use the contentWindow.focus() method.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var iframe = $("[ID OF IFRAME]")[0];
         iframe.contentWindow.focus();
     });
```

or if you would like it to be inline on the iframe tag, you can add the following.

```
onload="this.contentWindow.focus()"
```

Comment: the frame still doesnt have sound.

Comment: can you try using the following: $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#iframe").click();
     });

Comment: what I want is for the script I found in the game to return true.